# Is $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(X \le x, Y>x)$ not the same as $\sum_{x=2}^{\infty} P(X<x|Y=x)P(Y=x)$?

Tags: probability, inequality, summation, random-variables

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate $P(X<Y)$ for discrete random variables, taking values in the positive integers (so excluding 0). I've come up with a few ways. In my consideration the two in the title should be the same, but when I try it out in an example, they are not.

Even more so, $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} P(X \le x, Y>x)$ seems to be incorrect, and  $\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}  P(X<x|Y=x)P(Y=x)$ seems to be correct. Any thoughts on why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X \leq x \cap Y > x) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq x \mid Y > x\right)\mathbb{P}\left(Y > x\right) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(Y > x \mid X \leq x\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X \leq x\right)$$
Computationally, however, I'm not sure how useful this would be. Another way would be to define $Z = Y - X$ and calculate $\mathbb{P}(Z > 0)$, so that
$$\mathbb{P}(Y > X) = \mathbb{P}(Z > 0) = \sum\limits_{z=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(Z = z)$$

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the alternative way, I hadn't thought about it like that :) (Even though I think your sum has to start at z = 1, because starting at z = 0 includes the case Y = X).

Comment: @Anil Ah yes, that's right.